# How to round down to nearest whole decimal in PHP

Tags: php, rounding, floor

Not sure if I've explained the question properly but below are some random examples of what I need to happen

20.39 to become 20.30

40.55 to become 40.50

9.22 to become 9.20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`floor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) after multiplying by 10 and then divide by 10 again. To keep the second decimal place after rounding, use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
$values = [20.39,40.55,9.22];
foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo number_format(floor($value * 10) / 10, 2);
}
```

Output:

```
20.30
40.50
9.20
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to keep the zeros at the end? So the outputs would be.. 20.30, 40.50 and 9.20

Comment: Yes, you can do that using [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), see my edited answer